# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class::0x000.. Rails 6 AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I built a table that allows you to edit records inline; the issue I am having is the partial won't re-render the data after its refreshed in the view. I am using a separate controller to handle the update/edit partial rendering. I can successfully render the form inline, I just cant get past the updating the partial error without receiving an undefined local variable. How can I re-render the partial for my update.js.erb action in a different controller?

**charts/facility_chart.html.erb**

```
<div class="divTable greyGridTable">
<div class="divTableHeading">
  <div class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableHead">Date</div>
  <% @facility_chart_events.select(:name).distinct.each |event_name| %>
   <div class="divTableHead"><%= event_name %></div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="divTableHead">Update/Change</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableBody">
 <% @facility_event_grids.each do |event| %>
   <%= content_tag :div, class: 'divTableRow', id: dom_id(event) do %>
   <%= render partial: "facility_event_trackers/facility_event_tracker", :locals => {event: event} %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

**_inline_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: facility_event_tracker, class: 'divTableRow', id: dom_id(facility_event_tracker, 'inline_form'), local: false do |f| %>
 <div class="divTableCell">
   <%= chart_tracker_grid_date(f.object.start_time) %>
 </div>
<div class="divTableCell">
  <%= text_field :event_count, label: false %>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="divTableCell">
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'ui black button basic' %>
</div>
```

**charts_controller.rb**

```
def facility_chart
 @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
 @facility_events_grids = @facility.facility_event_trackers.order(start_time: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(40)
 end
```

**facility_event_trackers_controller.rb**

```
def edit
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
 if @facility_event_tracker.update(facility_event_tracker_params)
   format.js {}
 else
 format.js {}
end
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker) %>').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<%= j render 'inline_form', facility_event_tracker: @facility_event_tracker %>");
```

**update.js.erb**

```
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker, 'inline_form') %>').remove()
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker, 'inline_form') %>').innerHTML = <%= j render "facility_event_trackers/facility_event_tracker", facility_event_tracker: @facility_event_tracker %>"
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker) %>').style.display = 'table-row'
```

**Rails Console Error**

// partial fails to re-render for update

```
ActionView::Tempalate::Error (undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class:0x00000>:0x00005>):
1: <div class="divTableCell"><%= chart_tracker_grid_date(event.start_time) %>...
2: <div class="divTableCell"><%= event.event_count %></div>

app/views/facility_event_trackers/_facility_event_tracker.html.erb:1
app/views/facility_event_trackers/update.js.erb
```

Comment: How is `event` defined in `<div class="divTableCell"><%= event.event_count %></div>` ? It looks like there is a local variable in your file, can you share that whole view? I can't find this line anywhere in the code you shared.

Comment: When I update the form and pass it to the update method in facility_chart_trackers_controller.rb it updates without issue, *if* I redirect. When I pass the data to the update.js.erb. It doesn't remember the data for the partial, to send a correct response.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only be passing the `update.js.erb` file the `facility_event_tracker` object and not the event object:

```
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker, 'inline_form') %>').innerHTML = <%= j render "facility_event_trackers/facility_event_tracker", facility_event_tracker: @facility_event_tracker %>"
```

I recommend you add:

```
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@facility_event_tracker, 'inline_form') %>').innerHTML = <%= j render "facility_event_trackers/facility_event_tracker", facility_event_tracker: @facility_event_tracker, event: @event %>"
```